# Use of SIGCONT with CLONE() and CLONE_STOPPED flag set for Linux

Tags: linux, thread-safety, linux-kernel, pthreads

I am trying to implement a thread create/run function using clone().I am planning to use CLONE_STOPPED flag to create a child thread but let it wait for starting execution until i send SIGCONT to the child thread created.The doubt i am having is what will be the state of parent thread when it sends SIGCONT to the child and the child resumes execution.Will the parent thread be suspended ? or continue running ?.How can we configure this.?

THanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parent will continue to be runnable.  Whether it actually runs simultaneously with the child or interleaved depends on how many processor cores you have and how the scheduler decides to run them; you should assume it runs simultaneously.

The `CLONE_STOPPED` flag has been deprecated for years, and was actually removed during the latest kernel merge window.  You should not be using it - use thread synchronisation primitives (perhaps built on `futex()`) instead.

Comment: I'm curious how you might implement your suggestion.  Keep around an anonymous shared mmaped page so you can put a futex on it?  Maybe use POSIX semaphores?

Comment: I was thinking of using futex() for the same then came accross this construct.As you said if it is obsolete i have to go with futex.Do you have any pointers to conditional variable implementation using futex?

Comment: @Karmastan: The OP talks about creating *threads*, which implies use of `CLONE_VM`, so the futex can be placed anywhere.  If you were not using `CLONE_VM`, then yes a `MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_SHARED` page would be sufficient.

Comment: @notytony: The only one I'm familiar with is [NPTL](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=tree;f=nptl;h=45ed66c63a44abeb70876f3431a7147cdcc7292c;hb=HEAD)

Comment: You're right!  All the talk of parents, children, and signals must have made me read right over the word "thread."  Futexes are definitely the way to go.